# correct timestamp dtype to cast BigQuery TIMESTAMP

Tags: numpy, pandas, casting, timestamp, google-bigquery

I have a table with a column timestamp in type TIMESTAMP in BigQuery. When I display it on my console, I can see timestamps as follows: `2015-10-19 21:25:35 UTC`

I then download my table using the BigQuery API, and when I display the result of the query, I notice that this timestamp has been converted in some kind of very big integer like `1.445289935E9`

Therefore, in order to load this table as a `pandas.DataFrame`, I have to convert it back to a pandas compatible timestamp. How can I do that? In other words, what numpy or pandas dtype shall I use in my pandas.read_csv to load my bigquery timestamp in a numpy/pandas timestamp?

Comment: This looks strange if we treat this as epoch time then it gives: `In [230]:

pd.to_datetime(1.445289935E9, unit='s')
Out[230]:
Timestamp('2015-10-19 21:25:35')` which is different to what you reported unless your value is just an example

Comment: Maybe this can be interesting (read directly into DataFrame with `read_gbq`): http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#google-bigquery-experimental

Comment: @EdChum I miss copy the value, sorry

Comment: So have you tried what joris suggested or does using `to_datetime` work?

Comment: Please cancel this -1, it does not make sense.

Comment: @EdChum I don't want to use read_gbq for various reasons. Your to_datetime works but I would prefer a dtype so I can give a type dictionnary to my DataFrame(), or use in astype()

Comment: I don't understand the `dtype` requirement where will this be used? Can't you just pass the `dtypes` of the df?

Comment: @EdChum I want to write a function which automatically parse the data. I download the schema of the table and when I see a BigQuery 'TIMESTAMP', I want to know in what python type I have to cast my data.

Comment: When I load it "as is", the value 1.445289935E9 is not recognized as a timestamp by pandas. So I would like to write for instance df['time_series'] = df['time_series'].astype(numpy.datetime64) but this does not work because the conversion fails.

Comment: You have to use `to_datetime` with `unit='s'` to do the conversion so it treats it as epoch time